# Read a diagram plotted with Librosa (Python) and create (e.g.) an audio file from it

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, diagram, librosa

I use the module **Librosa** in Python to make a "click-beat-diagram" to a song (.wav-file). Please read the short explanation on the Librosa-website [here](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.clicks.html#librosa.clicks).

I use the following code:

```
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#loading the music-file (wav)
y, sr = librosa.load("C://Users/Max/Downloads/example.wav", duration=30)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)

#plotting the diagram
librosa.display.waveplot(y_beat_times, sr=sr, label='Beat clicks', ax=ax[1])
ax[0].legend()
ax[0].label_outer()
ax[0].set_title(None)
```

This plots a diagram, which shows click-signals depending on the time. It looks like this:

[image: diagram - plottet "clicks"]

My question now is, if it is possible to read out this diagram and for example play a sound every time a click signal comes (the diagram makes a spike)? That is, to make an mp3 file from this diagram, for example.

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me an idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance

P.S.:I know there is already a similar question, but it does not relate to Librosa and is also not so well understood by me.

Comment: To go from an plot of a waveform back to pcm audio data the only way I can think is to 1. Rasterise the image, 2. March through vertical pixel wide slices 3. Record the coordinate of the waveform line by detecting colour 4. Normalise coordinates to -1 to +1 for y and a sample index for x. There would have to be some knowns like sampling rate or duration plotted.

Comment: Which is the existing related post that you mention?

Comment: You should not read out from the graph when you have the click data, you can just write the click track to a file using soundfile.write